# Visual Studio - MSI Install project - Overwrite previous version

Tags: msbuild, windows-installer, versioning

I have an MSI installer project that installs a windows service.

For every release manually I have to change the Version number in the properties box.

`For Ex: 1.0.35.`

How do I change the same from the command line by passing a parameter instead of changing it in the solution file.

In the `.proj` file I use the following command to build by solution file.

`<Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe&quot; $(work_dir)\myproj\client\windows\msm32b\msm32b.sln /Build"/>`

This command packages the binaries such as `dll's`, `exe's`, `sys files` etc as a MSI file. Currently I am changing the Version number manually in the properties box. How do I change the version from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this applies to an MSI project, or if the solution is appropriate for you, but it may be worth looking into:

If the version number you are refering to is the same as the assembly version (accessible using the property `Application.ProductVersion`), you can make at least the last part of it increment automatically for each build.

Open the file `AssemblyInfo.cs` (found under the `Properties` folder in the Solution Explorer). At the bottom of this file, the version number is shown. It should look something like the following:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.3.4")]
```

If you change it to the following, the last two parts of it will be generated automatically.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.*")]
```